# Checking Sudoku solution

Tags: sudoku

Rule for checking the correct solution for a sudoku problem are :-

1. Grid size is 9x9, divided into 9 regions of 3x3
2. Each row must contain all digits from 1-9
3. Each column must contain all digits from 1-9
4. Each 3x3 square must contain all digits from 1-9

Most of the solutions check for the below 3 constraints :-

1. Each row must contain all digits from 1-9
2. Each column must contain all digits from 1-9
3. Each 3x3 square must contain all digits from 1-9

My question is "If i check for the first two constraints i.e.

1. Each row must contain all digits from 1-9
2. Each column must contain all digits from 1-9

Does it not enough to meet the 3rd constraint also?"

In other words does anybody know any sudoku solution where digits 1-9 are uniquely placed in rows and columns but are not unique in 3X3 square?

Comment: This question seems to be more about sudoku.

Comment: Wrong site for this type of question imo.

Comment: I believe 3rd constraint is not needed, but still - this is not the correct place for this question.

Comment: Sorry for the post. I was just trying to code the checking the solution part. Just saw many such post related to sudoku on this site, hence posted it!!!..Sorry again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
9 1 2 | 3 4 5 | 6 7 8
8 9 1 | 2 3 4 | 5 6 7
- - - + - - - + - - -
7 8 9 | 1 2 3 | 4 5 6
6 7 8 | 9 1 2 | 3 4 5
5 6 7 | 8 9 1 | 2 3 4
- - - + - - - + - - -
4 5 6 | 7 8 9 | 1 2 3
3 4 5 | 6 7 8 | 9 1 2
2 3 4 | 5 6 7 | 8 9 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must check the third constraint. See the following solution that passes the first two constraints, but not the third.

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
 [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2],
 [4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3],
 [5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4],
 [6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5],
 [7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6],
 [8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
 [9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```